# Determining variance from sum of two random uncorrelated variables

Tags: statistics, variance

I understand $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. But what if I add a constant into the left hand side?

For example, $Var(2+3X+Y)=$?

$9Var(X)+Var(Y)?$

I'm not sure if I get it right.. simply just ignore the effect of the constant?

Comment: Start with (or prove it from the definition of variance if you don't know it, it's quite easy) that $\operatorname{Var}(X+a) = \operatorname{Var}(X)$ for any constant $a$ (if you do not want to use the definition, note that $X$, $a$ are independent -- since $a$ is a constant -- so $\operatorname{Var}(X+a) = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(a)$  and $\operatorname{Var}(a) = ...$). Your answer is right, and will easily come from that.